# JQuery: Determine which SELECT among the children has changed

Tags: jquery, select

I have 3 grouped select Month, Day and Year... I am changing the contents of Day SELECT based on the values of Month and Year SELECTs. example is I will make the options in Day up to 28 if the Month is February etc. I want a function which runs if the user changed the value of Month or Year but ignore if the Day is selected. I have this function

```
$("#ui-1 .ui-select").children().change(
    function(){
    ...if the Day select has been changed exit this function
    });
});
```

I have this HTML....

```
            <div id="ui-1">
            <div class="ui-select" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                <select data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" id="Datepicker_0_0" name="Datepicker_0_0">
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    .... and so on
                </select>
                <select data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" id="Datepicker_0_1" name="Datepicker_0_1">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    ... up to here
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
                <select data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" id="Datepicker_0_2" name="Datepicker_0_2">
                    <option value="1975">1975</option>
                    <option value="1976">1976</option>
                    <option value="1977">1977</option>
                    ...up to here
                    <option value="2050">2050</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` points to the element from which the event originated, so you could use `if(this.id == 'Datepicker_0_1') return;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ui-1 .ui-select").children().change(
    function(){
        if(this.id == "Datepicker_0_0") return;
        //rest of code
    });
});
```

Check whether the `id` attribute of the `select` element equals `"Datepicker_0_0"` (that's the identifier of you "Day" select element).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify either an `id` or an `name` for each select.
You can figure out which select it it by `$(this).attr('id')` or `'name'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(){
   if( $( this ).attr( 'name' ) == 'Datepicker_0_1' )
      return;
});
```